# Location of OSX Lion Mail Server sent mail

Tags: email, osx-server, server.app

I had to restore a mac mini server I use for web and mail hosting. Since the restore was due to a software problem, I had to do from scratch instead of recovering from a disk clone. I copied from the old mini backup all the mail accounts directories under /Library/Server/Mail/Data/..., and I've got back all received mail for every account, but NOT the sent mail. I guess sent mail is stored in a different location, but can't figure out where.

Does anyone know what I have to copy to restore also sent mail?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found my error. The sent messages folder is into the same directory of the inbox, under /Library/Server/Mail/Data/..., but it's hidden From Finder and `ls` as it is named with a . To start the folder name - .../.Sent Messages.

My mistake was to copy the contents of the backup folder to the newly created folder without checking the presence of hidden folders. My mistake is your answer if you fall into the same "trap".

Comment: Thank you for posting this - I'm sure it will be handy for others.